# How to make html map draggable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My team members and I are having problems making an HTML map draggable when the mouse is over a defined area. If the user clicks on an area that isn't defined within the map, then they can drag, but if not, they can't drag.

Here's the HTML for the map:

```
<img src="/unknown1.jpg" id="map" usemap="#map" width="1632px" height="866px"></div></div>
<map name="map">
    <area target="" alt="O" title="O" href="" coords="1354,114,1347,203,1317,271,1209,143,1292,82" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="P" title="P" href="" coords="1202,142,1314,270,1254,378,1122,291,1091,203,1147,170" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Q" title="Q" href="" coords="1122,297,1251,385,1261,478,1243,543,1223,602,1184,641,1157,656,1078,579,1115,532,1122,483,1111,431,1085,383,1115,347" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="N" title="N" href="" coords="1080,205,1115,286,1112,346,1083,381,1030,347,984,344,933,354,897,372,826,307,953,256,1010,234" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="M" title="M" href="" coords="759,278,811,307,919,266,1006,230,1065,207,1145,170,1196,139,1153,112,1026,168,918,206,858,208,795,201" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="V" title="V" href="" coords="1026,438,1083,389,1114,445,1117,490,1108,526,1091,550,1076,575,1027,519,1039,477,1034,458" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="R" title="R" href="" coords="883,573,798,627,896,693,995,729,1081,736,1134,710,1151,670,1150,659,1094,601,1072,586,1030,607,981,608,933,602" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="S" title="S" href="" coords="944,517,887,568,935,598,978,602,1020,601,1055,589,1070,584,1026,524,983,529" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="W" title="W" href="" coords="952,438,970,432,1003,432,1019,444,1029,464,1029,480,1023,503,1014,514,998,519,984,519,968,516,955,510,944,504,939,496,939,480,939,467,944,450" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="T" title="T" href="" coords="893,379,945,435,938,460,933,473,932,496,936,513,925,526,903,543,884,558,861,516,854,477,864,421" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="U" title="U" href="" coords="897,375,916,366,965,353,993,347,1017,349,1043,359,1069,375,1079,382,1066,398,1049,409,1029,425,1023,437,995,425,980,425,952,432" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="L" title="L" href="" coords="749,284,834,321,857,343,889,373,860,411,854,434,850,463,854,509,864,536,880,565,853,586,752,481,691,415" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="K" title="K" href="" coords="690,425,765,503,825,569,843,588,792,621,772,633,739,607,680,535,645,497" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="J" title="J" href="" coords="637,509,691,561,727,599,755,628,699,695,644,656,595,595,589,565,611,536,625,519" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="F" title="F" href="" coords="478,173,677,389,709,363,726,317,743,277,502,161" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="G" title="G" href="" coords="530,245,683,403,638,493,465,307" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="H" title="H" href="" coords="462,313,632,497,606,536,570,552,484,491,429,441,380,372" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="C" title="C" href="" coords="531,241,441,138,331,162,464,303" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="B" title="B" href="" coords="322,169,458,308,373,369,234,212,275,189" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="E" title="E" href="" coords="748,272,772,202,471,86,468,143,603,205" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="D" title="D" href="" coords="200,143,443,86,449,133,329,156,230,210" shape="poly">
</map>
```

We're using jquery to make the map draggable and maphilight so that sections on the map get highlighted when hovered over.

```
$('.center').draggable({
  scroll: false
});
  
$('#map').maphilight();
```

We tried using our own function to make the map draggable using this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp but it didn't work.

If you need any more code, please let me know. I would be happy to provide it.

Comment: Needs more info. It is unclear whether you want the whole map to be draggable or only the single areas while the map stays static. Also, the elements of class `.center` that you're referring to in the jquery code are missing from the HTML part. In any case, I'd think the standard "draggable" libraries would not apply to map/area, as those are not standard DOM objects (they only define clickable areas on an `<img>` object ... okay, now that I think about that, that info may be obsolete in modern browsers).

Comment: Oh, could it be that your question is a duplicate of [Use image map as the handle for jQuery UI Draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231506/use-image-map-as-the-handle-for-jquery-ui-draggable)?